# What determines when I'm prompted for a Candroid?

Tags: kamen-rider-memory-of-heroez

In Kamen Rider: Memory of Heroez, sometimes when I'm in-between battles I'll get prompted to set up a Candroid to help me in the next fight. I seemingly have no control over when these prompts appear or what type of candroid I'm offered. If I don't accept the prompt, the option to summon the Candroid disappears after a little while.

What determines when these Candroid prompts appear? Is the type of Candroid offered determined at random?

[image: Being offered a candroid]